# Change to an different keyboard layout when entering passwords

Tags: keyboard, ios, password

I've just bought the Ipad 2, all my existing passwords that I need to use (mails web services etc) are in Arabic characters.

I have added the Arabic Keyboard and am able to use it in normal text fields, but I cannot switch to it when I try to type into a password field.  If I already have the Arabic keyboard selected when typing a username, it switches back to the normal keyboard when I move to the password field.  Because of this I am unable to log into anything which uses an Arabic password.

I tried with Safari and Opera Mini browser.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: My guess is that due to the calligraphic nature of Arabic text, it's hard for the system to decide exactly what constitutes a "character" for the hiding-passwords-with-bullets feature. However, the more I think about that, the less likely it seems!

Answer (score 2):

I can see that this is likely to be very restrictive until you find a solution, so I offer this workaround to ease things while other answers come in.  If you enter your password into your username field, then select it, copy it, and type over the top with your actual user name, you can then paste the password into the password field..  This is 3 extra taps overall, but will at least allow you to use your logins in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I am using copy paste now, and using google keyboard.  But you cannot change the password keyboard.  It seems locked.

So if your password has characters otherwise found on a google keyboard, you won't be able to type it into a password field.  Copy paste is the best solution i found, so type it in the username text box or somewhere else using google keyboard and copy it over.

Comment: Any custom keyboard has access to any characters you type (obviously). There are good reasons why you don't want to give your passwords to 3rd party keyboards :-)

Comment: Im using a google keyboard, i migrated from android. Likewise non 3rd party keyboards also have access to my password, obviously.

Comment: The OS and the keyboards it supplies have access to anything anyway

Comment: I find the iOS keyboard not intuitive, ie if i want to place a cursor in the middle of a word, i have to hold down space,  I also have to know where all the hidden keys would be, ie if looking for ` i need to know to long press the key that looks the same but is point in the opposite direction.  Will have to try get used to it and learn Apples way of doing things.

Comment: There are good reasons why you don't want to give your passwords to Apple, too, so what's your point?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried hitting this key?

[image]

Or you can try [this free app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/free-arabic-keyboard/id380742315?mt=8) which will allow you to use an Arabic keyboard on your iPad.

**EDIT:**
Here is a great [walk trough](http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/) on how to do this...

Comment: the key doesn't show up when typing a password, this is the problem

Comment: Have you selected multiple languages in Settings < Keyboard < International (I'm not 100% of the naming since I don't have an English iDevice with me at the moment)

Comment: I have already the Arabic keyboard layout on the system, I'm using Ipad2 so no need to this app in my case

Comment: Yes i have both English and Arabic keyboards added

Comment: And you don't see a global key next to your space bar?

Comment: yes ! just in the password fields

Comment: So, every time you would like to enter a password, the keyboard switches back to English?

Comment: exactly, even if i typed on the other fields with the Arabic layout

Comment: @Michiel  Do YOU see the globe key when you are in a password field?